# What are these odd distortions on far away textures?

Tags: graphics, unity, mesh

I'm currently writing a simple voxel engine just to get some practice in, and I'm coming across some odd issues. In order to generate terrain, I create a mesh and then assign UV coordinates on a texture atlas to each vertex. Whenever I run the game, I get strange distortions, like these:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've tried doing a few things so far:

- Generating mip maps for the texture atlas.
- Play around with the max size of the texture atlas.
- Play around with the format of the texture atlas.

Unfortunately, none of these have worked so far. As of right now, the import settings on the texture atlas itself look like this:

[image]

Is there any way I can get rid of these obnoxious distortions?

Comment: I'm not so sure the mipmapping was properly enabled. Because it looks very much like the textures are not mipmapped. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12150/perspective-in-early-pseudo-3d-games. I'd suggest making a flat world, so you can get a real good feel for the effect.

Comment: Serious question here, but is this unrelated to anisotropic filtering?

Comment: It might also be worth looking at the shader. You have a low-res pixely aesthetic, but are you achieving it with actually using low-res textures with a shader without texture filtering or are you using high-res textures which just look low-res?

Comment: @ssb No, I don't believe so. The import settings on the texture atlas have the filtering mode set to point.

Comment: @Philipp I am using low-red textures.

Comment: I see that you have mip mapping disabled. Can you try it with "Generate Mip Maps" on and see if it helps?

Comment: @Philipp I've already tried generating mip maps, it didn't have any effect, and honestly made it look worse.

Comment: Have you tried activating some sort of anisotropic filtering?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This distortion pattern is an aliasing artifact caused by point sampling the wrong mip level of a texture. Change the "Filter Mode" from "Point" to bilinear, and make sure to check "Generate Mip Maps". (There is rarely a good reason to disable mip-map generation.) As some have suggested in the comments, anisotropic filtering will work even better to eliminate this kind of artifact.

The problem is caused because at a distance each square in the checkerboard pattern is almost, but not quite, the width of a screen pixel. The pattern of texture samples overlaid on the texture checkerboard pattern gives rise to a new visual pattern. Mip maps and anisotropic sampling will cause the GPU to average together neighboring texels so that distant pixels blend to green instead of generating a pattern.

Here's an article with images that explain what you're seeing:
https://paroj.github.io/gltut/Texturing/Tut15%20Anisotropy.html